# Load Colorbox multi image gallery from node display

Tags: javascript

I need help understanding/implementing display of multi images from a node directly to a colorbox popup.

I've created a new content type with an Image field, set to allow unlimited images. Revised display setting to colorbox.

I've loaded multiple images into the node.

**Use case 1**: From menu item, directly display a colorbox popup which references a node's images 1 of n (I don't need/want to display the node) .

For this use case, I've added the specific node number in the Path and added colorbox-load class. The result of this, clicking on menu item, the node displays with images (as colorbox popup), then when I click on any image, I get the colorbox multi-image popup (which hangs the page).

How do I go direct to colorbox multi-image popup from a menu rather than seeing all the images in a node first?

**Use Case 2**: Create a link within an article page to directly display a multi-image popup of an individual node's images.

I've created an  tag, added colorbox-load class, and get same results as above.